# How can I get themedisplay object in XYZServiceImpl?

Tags: java, web-services, liferay

How can I get themedisplay object in XYZServiceImpl?
My scenarios is like I am trying to fetch all document using web services but I need to WebDAV URL for each document using which user can download document.

I have done some googling for the same and I found following methods which provides the webdav and thumbnail but for that I required themedisplay object.

1.) **DLUtil.getWebDavURL(themeDisplay, folder, fileEntry);**

2.) **DLUtil.getThumbnailSrc(fileEntry, dlFileShortcut, themeDisplay)**

Also I need to check permission for each folder and document to get permission checker object I need themedisplay object.

Can anyone help me to get out from this as soon as possible OR any alternate solution to get this object?

Comment: It's easy: You first let us know of all other places where you've asked the same question (so that this doesn't cause duplicate work, here and there), then you go there yourself and read what's already written in exactly those threads that you have answered to yourself. The answer is already in there. If you don't understand how it applies to you, at least let us know what you already tried (as you have obviously found some information about this problem already)

Comment: I have asked the same questions in Liferay forum but I didn't find any answer in forum.

Comment: I was hoping that you embedded the link to https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/57571861 so that others can see this quickly without searching. You're generating duplicate work by not posting those links and this lowers the motivation to help you. And when you expect an answer "as soon as possible", increasing motivation should be all you're doing

Comment: I have added this question link in liferay forum.

Comment: I have gone through the liferay forum thread but which provide answer for liferay wsdl web services while I am using liferay json web service.

Answer (score 0):

The only (maintainable) way to get themeDisplay in your API calls is by requiring it as a parameter to the interface. In general though, this is a bad habit, as themeDisplay contains a lot of stuff from the front end layer, and typically your services should be well decoupled from the front layer. In fact, they might be called from contexts where there is no themeDisplay, in pure API calls.

Thus, the methods that you point to are made to be used from places where ThemeDisplay is available, but I'd like them better if they just required the necessary details instead of requiring the whole lot of themeDisplay information. On the other hand, that would make [4 instead of 1](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.2.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/documentlibrary/util/DLImpl.java#L1030) parameter

If you build a service, you shouldn't require a themeDisplay as parameter. This might be easier said than done - it'll be more work for you, but provide cleaner code. On the other hand, you might have to duplicate the method that I've linked to above. There is no "correct" way to solve the problem under these circumstances, you'll have to judge for yourself

*Edit*: Answering to your comment: You can't get themeDisplay in a call that's coming in through the API - it's just not there. Now if you *really* need it and there's *no* way around: Look at the actual implementation of the method that you're going to call (which I've conveniently linked above) and create & initialize a ThemeDisplay object with the data that is required by the method you're going to call. And always remember that this is a workaround, don't do this routinely

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am creating a web service to fetch all documents using existing table so for thhi I am following your below answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762532/how-to-create-liferay-json-web-service-for-existing-tables. Like I have created blank service builder and I am adding my custom code to fetch all document in this serviceImpl, Now how can I get themedisplay object here without extending any class or methods.